# Android phone has to replug the usb to run application from eclipse

Tags: android, usb, offline

since several days ago, I found that there was not any running android device in the "Android Device Chooser" windoo run aw anymore when I started tn android application from eclipse. But my android phone (a device produced by HUAWEI and running android 4.1) was actually connected with my computer with debug mode on and it had no such problem before. A temporary method to fix this problem is to replug the usb cable of my phone every time I run an application which is very inconvenient and hurt the usb port badly.

An interesting thing is my device is in the devices list with online status in the DDMS perspective. Does any one know what the cause of this problem or this means the usb port of my phone is broken?
(ps:no adb disconnected error is presented)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `minSdkVersion` of your Application to be less than the `Android Version` installed on your Device.

You can do it by changing the `android:minSdkVersion` value in your `Manifest.xml` File.

In your case this should be `android:minSdkVersion="14"`

Edit :
*Use ADB Restart Method*:
1. Launch Terminal.
2. Navigate to `Platform-tools` directory (It is located in Android SDKs directory).
3. type the following commands in Terminal 
Command # 1: `./adb kill-server` 
Command # 2: `./adb start-server`
4. Hopefully, your Android Device will be visible when you run your `Android Application Project`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The minsdkversion i set is 8 ,much lower than my phone's running version. It does not work.

Comment: Ok, what OS are you using Mac/Linux/Windows ?

Comment: mac, but i think it has nothing to do with my computer os because this problem never happened before until several days ago.

Comment: No.But I restarted my computer and it still not work. I also tried this with another android phone and got the same problem.

Comment: I guess the reason very likely is my computer's(laptop) usb port got problem(one of the two usb ports is totally down). I will try  on a desktop computer and see what will happen.

Comment: Oh, it may be a probability. Is this your USB Port's problem ?